# rosdep install doesn't find libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm developing my stacks in which I have a certain package that depends on gstreamer.
I need to install this libraries:

- `libgstreamer0.10-dev`
- `libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev`

I defined this dependencies both in `manifest.xml` and `rosdep.yaml` (is this correct?). However on some PCs, all of them with Ubuntu 11.10, `rosdep-install` fails with the following output:

```
.../RGBCamera$ rosdep install RGBCamera
Failed to find rosdep libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev for package RGBCamera on OS:ubuntu version:oneiric
rosdep install ERROR:
failed to install libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev
```

This is the content of `manifest.xml`

```
<package>
    <description brief="RGB Camera">
        This package contains the dirver for the RGB Camera
    </description>
    <rosdep name="libgstreamer0.10-dev"/>
    <rosdep name="libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev"/>
    <depend package="rtt"/>
    <depend package="ocl"/>
    <depend package="rtt_sensor_msgs"/>
</package>
```

This is the content of `rosdep.yaml`

```
libgstreamer0.10-dev:
  ubuntu:
    oneiric: 
      apt:
        packages: libgstreamer0.10-dev
libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev:
  ubuntu:
    oneiric: 
      apt:
        packages: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev
```

What's the problem here?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29775/rosdep-install-doesn%27t-find-libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev/) by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2012-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be using the key 'oneiric' not '11.10' in your rosdep.yaml  See [REP 111](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0111.html#os-version-identifiers) for specifics on OS identifiers.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on 2012-03-15**:
@tfoote Thanks, I modified the `rosdep.yaml` as reported in the modified question. However it still doesn't work.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-03-15**:
Where is your rosdep.yaml file in relation to your package and stack?

**Comment by [LucaGhera](https://answers.ros.org/users/871/lucaghera/) on 2012-03-15**:
@tfoote the `rosdep.yaml` is in the package root, the same folder of the `manifest.xml`. `stack.xml` is in the upper level folder.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-03-19**:
@LucaGhera it should be a peer of the stack.xml  rosdep only searchs inside a package path if that package is not in a stack.